# Where to ask questions about debugging?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

By chance I noticed that [an old question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704657/is-there-a-tool-to-log-call-stacks-when-a-specified-applications-ui-hangs) got closed as off-topic. It was about debugging on site at the customer's. Now I'm wondering where I should have asked such a question instead? Programmers Stack Exchange doesn't seem to be the right place either. Any ideas?

Comment: I find it funny that someone feels the urge to downvote my linked question just because I posted it here... Come on, it's already closed! :)

Comment: It appears to be asking for a tool, it doesn't appear to be about debugging remotely.

Comment: I understand that the question was closed in accordance to the rules. But where should I ask such a question? Here you have all those people doing stuff like this every day but you can't ask them.

Comment: upvoted solely for "Programmers Stack Exchange [doesn't seem to be the right place](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6840/31260 "way too often people misunderstand this")" :)

Comment: @gnat you are the duplicate master :)

Comment: @vba4all that's typically easy when one figures the [right tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation?sort=frequent) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem to me that [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) would be the best suitable site for such a question.

Comment: Thank you, this one's certainly interesting. Though it surely lacks the great number of developers that visit SO. :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your question is that you're not asking how to debug remotely; you're asking for a tool.

"How do I debug remotely?" Is not off topic.

"Is there a tool that allows me to debug remotely?" *is* off topic.

The former can have a tool as its solution; the latter will only have tools as its solution.

Comment: Well, I had a certain idea of what I needed so I asked whether there existed something that could help me realize it. I could have played dumb and ask without any specifics. Don't get me wrong, I understand that my question (back then unknowingly) violated the rules. I just don't really agree with them.